# How can I figure out this electronic charge unit in Quantum Computation?

Tags: electrons, charge, si-units, unit-conversion

I stacked in middle of some conversation of electronic charge. We aware about the electronic charge, $$ e= 1.602\times {10}^{-19} C $$
To work in particle physics, I saw in some book that $$ e=3.795 {(eVÅ)}^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
So, how can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second equation is dimensionally correct only in [Gaussian CGS units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) where the electrostatic potential energy between two electrons is $e^2/r$ rather than $e^2/(4\pi\epsilon_0 r)$ as in SI units.

To see how it works in Gaussian CGS units, convert the atomic physics energy unit used here (eV) to the CGS energy unit (erg) using

$$1\text{ eV}=1.602\times10^{-12}\text{ erg}$$

and convert the atomic physics length unit used here (Å) to the CGS length unit (cm) using

$$1\text{ Å}=10^{-8}\text{ cm}.$$

Then the second equation is

$$e=3.795[(1.602\times10^{-12}\text{ erg})(10^{-8}\text{ cm})]^{1/2}=4.803\times 10^{-10}\text{ statC},$$

which is the correct [charge of the electron in statcoulombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge), the Gaussian CGS unit of charge.

What the second equation is telling you is that two electrons with a separation of 1 angstrom have an electrostatic energy of 3.795 electron-volts.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.